NOPASSWD Sudo on Ubuntu 24.04 not working
I have setup my container with the following in my /etc/sudoers file
username    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
This works in previous versions, (22.04, 20.04) but in Ubuntu 24.04 I'm getting this error:

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper sudo: a password is required


Is username also a member of the sudo group? If so, where did you place the entry relative to the default %sudo group rule? Order is important - see for example Sudoers file, enable NOPASSWD for user, all commands

@steeldriver thanks for the suggestion.
I tried as suggested, removing my change to the sudoers file and using the "usermod -aG sudo username" to no avail.
Essentially, previously I used the GID 1000 & UID 1000, which are now default to ubuntu group/user.
I've had to change my UID accordingly, but I suspect there is something else in the sudoers file going on here.
I'm going to see if I can update the sudoers file in my pipeline further.

Essentially my changes are after the
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
I'm even testing with adding the user in a separate file rather than updating the sudoers file, to no avail. The sudo command still fails when run through my CI in Jenkins.
Its as if the NOPASSWD setting is not being honoured.

The order is important
From the sudoers manual:
When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).
If you want that username does not enter the password each time he does a sudo and he is already a member of sudo, the entry in sudoers must be after the %sudo entry.
Correct
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Incorrect
# User privilege specification 
root      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


This worked for me

In my case, /etc/sudoers.d contains a file that overrides the permission. 10-installer. Removing this file fixed the issue, this file contains a single line override as following:
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

So the contents in the /etc/sudoers.d overrides the content in the sudoer.

In this instance, updating the %sudo setting in the /etc/sudoers file to NOPASSWD worked.
sed -i -e 's/^%sudo\tALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL/%sudo\tALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' /etc/sudoers

Before

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S
option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

After

sudo apt install vim -y WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI
interface. Use with caution in scripts. Reading package lists...

